# How to update AD LDS distinguishedName attribute to Single Value to No

Tags: ldap, adam, adlds

Currently the Single Value is set to Yes. How do i modify it ?

Why I am trying to do this is because I want to have a unique DN for each person.

Let say I have 2 person name is cn=Alice, i can do a cn=Alice+sn=Paul
so the dn will be unique

According to "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/3c96b56d-d7a7-46f1-9883-7d031f9fa01e"

Does this apply to AD LDS?

Comment: Please post the code that you have so far, if applicable. What have you tried? What do you get (including error messages) and what do you expect?

Comment: I have no clue on what to run as i cant get any information from google. I expect to be able to add "cn=Alice+sn=Paul" in dn, but AD LDS doesnt allow me to

Comment: Hello @newbieprogrammer,
I'm facing the same problem! did you find a solution for that ?